# How do I save a Form as an image to a file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my program I save a Chart by doing the following:

```
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    chart.SaveImage(saveFileDialog.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

But how do I save the whole Form where the chart is located?

Update:

I found a solution:

```
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    this.DrawToBitmap(bm, rect);
    bm.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

Comment: When a question is marked as duplicate, how do I find the message they refere to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There`s a

```
Control.DrawToBitmap
```

function that can be used on all controls.. So call this for your main Form.